# splitting lines in python with sentences and labels

Tags: python, file-handling

> I have a sample of a file with sentences and labels. How can it be split into sentences and labels?

A very, very, very slow-moving, aimless movie about a distressed, drifting young man.   0

Not sure who was more lost - the flat characters or the audience, nearly half of whom walked out.   0

Attempting artiness with black & white and clever camera angles, the movie disappointed - became even more ridiculous - as the acting was poor and the plot and lines almost non-existent.      0

Very little music or anything to speak of.      0

**output**
**list of sentences:**
['A very, very, very slow-moving, aimless movie about a distressed, drifting young man','Not sure who was more lost - the flat characters or the audience, nearly half of whom walked out']

**corresponding labels:**
['0','0']

Comment: Can you be more specific about what do you mean by split into sentences and labels? Do you want to store them in separate files? Perhaps an example of output format would make things clear

Comment: I need to store all the labels {0} separately and corresponding text sentences separately

Comment: I have added an answer to split text and Labels into separate lists. Please check

Comment: Did it work for you. If yes please mark  the answer accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the number after the last "."(dot) is the **Label**

For the given example when stored in a file 'yourdata.txt' the following code should produce 2 lists `sentence_list` and `label_list`. You can write the data in these lists to files separately then as requested by you.

```
fmov=open('yourdata.txt','r')
sentence_list=[]
label_list=[]
for f in fmov.readlines():
    lineinfo=f.split('.')
    sentenceline=".".join(lineinfo[0:-1])
    sentence_list.append(sentenceline)
    label_list.append(str(lineinfo[-1]).replace('\n',''))
print(sentence_list)
print(label_list) 

OUT:
['A very, very, very slow-moving, aimless movie about a distressed, drifting young man', 'Not sure who was more lost - the flat characters or the audience, nearly half of whom walked out', 'Attempting artiness with black & white and clever camera angles, the movie disappointed - became even more ridiculous - as the acting was poor and the plot and lines almost non-existent', 'Very little music or anything to speak of']
[' 0', ' 0', ' 0', ' 0']
```

Comment: Please please run `flake8` on your code. PEP8 ( https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ ) asks that you use identifiers like `sentence_list` and `label_list`.

Comment: @J_H Thanks, I did not know about flake8. Have edited the identifier names

Answer (score 0):

Is '0' the label?  If it's only one sentence, you can do a `string.split('.')` using a period as a delimiter.  Though this might catch some errors if you have a sentence with something like 'Mr.' or 'Mrs.' so you might need to add some if statements to handle those.